# Symfony 4: allow only active accounts to login

Tags: symfony, web, symfony4

So I'm using symfony 4 and I managed to add a field in the user's database table called "Active", if active equals 0 then the account is not activated and vice versa.
So what I'm trying to do is that whenever a user who's account is not active tries to login, a message or an alert shows and tells him that his account is currently inactive. While an active user connects without any problem.
I'm not using FOSUserBundle here. So can I do that manually ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can accomplish that using a [user checker](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_checkers.html).

Eg.:

```
namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserCheckerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class UserChecker implements UserCheckerInterface
{
    public function checkPreAuth(UserInterface $user): bool
    {
        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            return;
        }

        if (!$user->isActive()) {
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException(
                'Inactive account cannot log in'
            );
        }
    }

    public function checkPostAuth(UserInterface $user): bool
    {
        $this->checkPreAuth($user);
    }
}
```

Enable the checker:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            // skipped for brevity
            user_checker: App\Security\UserChecker
```

Comment: shouldn't I specify which property I'm using to check the account's activation first ?

Comment: What property dude. In the checker you invoke methods to verify if the user can log in or not.

Comment: ah ok thanks, it's just that I'm still new to Symfony

Comment: It's pretty enjoyable once you grasp the basics.